# System.InvalidProgramException : Cannot create boxed ByRef-like values. at at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I upgraded a project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6. After upgrading, some tests are failing with this error:

> System.InvalidProgramException : Cannot create boxed ByRef-like values.

Full Error Message:

> System.InvalidProgramException : Cannot create boxed ByRef-like
> values.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> at Castle.Proxies.StreamProxy.Write(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
>
> at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean
> flushEncoder)
>
> at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush().

It was working fine with .NET Core 3.1 with Visual Studio 2019.  After upgrading to .NET 6 I am getting this issue.

Am I missing something?

Comment: A [mre] would be nice)

Comment: It seems unlikely that this would be a bug in Visual Studio itself, vs in the framework, runtime or the compiler. (I'd expect you to be able to reproduce the issue without using VS at all.)

Comment: Could you pls share your project file?